# How to lock folder in java before writing file?

Tags: java, file, concurrency, synchronization

I have usecase where multiple thread can write file to a folder. At a given point of time I want to identify which is the latest file in that folder. 
Since I cannot use timestamp as it can be same for more than 1 file in the folder. So I want to lock the folder, generate sequence number by counting number of file in folder, write new file by using the generated sequence number, release lock. Is this possible in java?

Similarly while reading take the file with largest sequence number.

Chances of concurrent writing file to a folder is less so performance won't be an issue.

Comment: You could use a lock file to serialize the access.

Comment: Will lock file will work with folder as well?

Comment: I suggest you make it clear to yourself what a lock file is.

Comment: You cannot lock a folder for writing or reading by other processes (as long as you don't use functionality of the OS). But if you have a concurrent applciation you can synchronize the threads of your apllication.

Comment: Is this program the only thing writing to the folder, or should you protect against other applications too? Is there more than one instance of this program running, or is it just one process that can use an in-memory lock?

Comment: There is more than 1 java process which can write to this folder

Answer (score 1):

You can't use [`FileLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html) on a directory so you will have to handle locking in Java. You could do something like:

```
private final Object lock = new Object();

public void writeToNext(String dirPath) {
    synchronized(lock) {
        File dir = new File(dirPath);
        List<File> files = Arrays.asList(dir.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(File pathname) {
                return !pathname.isDirectory();
            }
        }));

        int numFiles = files.size();
        String nextFile = dir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + (numFiles + 1) + ".txt"; // get a path for the new file
        System.out.println("Writing to " + nextFile);
        // TODO write to file
    }
}
```

**Note**

You could implement your solution such that each write increments a counter somewhere and you can just use that to get the next value; only order and look for the last file if the counter hasn't been initialized.

Comment: Above locking will only prevent concurrency within thread. But in my case there will be more than 1 java process writing to this folder.

Comment: You could use a resource that is shared among the processes to synchronize the processes. For example a database with a table where you read from to check if there is a process which already is processing the folder. If not enter an entry for this process so other processes will know the folder is being processed.

Comment: Number of files in folder will be very less max 50. So I don't think I need to keep separate counter somewhere..chances of multiple thread writing to same folder is also less..not a usual day activity

Comment: @lucio without using any database etc cant we solve this? Don't want to involve any external system for the sake of simplicity

Answer (score 0):

*Using Java SE 7 or above:*

`WatchService` API allows tracking file operations (create, modify and delete file) in a specified directory. In this scenario create a watch service to track new files created in the specific folder. Each time a new file is created the file creating an event is triggered and the process allows do some user-defined action.

The file already has a created time attribute (`java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes`). This can be extracted as of type `java.nio.file.attribute.FileTime` which is in *millis* or can be a more specific `java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit` (this allows *nanosecond* precision). This gives a chance to be more specific about what is the newest file.

Also, there is an option to create a custom *user-defined file attribute* for any file. The attribute allows defining as key-value pair. This unique attribute value can be associated with a file to identify if its the latest. The following APIs allow creating and reading a custom file attribute: `java.nio.file.attribute.UserDefinedFileAttributeView` and `Files.getFileAttributeView()`.

I think using the above APIs and methods one can create an application to track the latest files created in a specified folder and perform a required action. Note there is no locking mechanism involved if one is using these APIs.

**EDIT** (included):

*Using a collection to retrieve latest file:*

A thread-safe collection can be used to store the filenames (or file path) and retrieve them LIFO (last-in-first-out). The watch service (or similar process) can store the filename of the (latest) file created in the folder to this collection. A read operation just gets the latest filename from this collection and work with it. One can consider `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedDeque` or `LinkedBlockingDeque` based on requirement.

**EDIT** (included):

*A possible solution's process diagram:*

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Use [File.createNewFile()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile--) in a loop for writing. Because it

> Atomically creates a new, empty file named by this abstract pathname if and only if a file with this name does not yet exist. The check for the existence of the file and the creation of the file if it does not exist are a single operation that is atomic with respect to all other filesystem activities that might affect the file.

Like this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class FileCreator {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String creatorId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        File dir = new File("dir");
        for (int filesCreated = 0; filesCreated < 1000; filesCreated++) {
            File newFile;
            for (int fileIdx = dir.list().length; ; fileIdx++) {
                newFile = new File(dir, "file-" + fileIdx + ".txt");
                if (newFile.createNewFile()) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(newFile)) {
                pw.println(creatorId);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Another option would be [Files.createFile(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createFile-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-). It throws an exception if the file already exists.

As for reading:

> Similarly while reading take the file with largest sequence number.

What's the question here? Just *take* it.